# Repeat unread SMS and missed calls alerts?

Tags: sms, calls, nokia-lumia-535, alert

Is it possible to repeat unread SMS alert and missed calls tune (Lumia 535)?

Similar functionality on iOS:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is currently not availiable in Windows Phone. You can vote for this Suggestion on the [Windows Phone UserVoice site](https://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2110491-repeat-notifications-for-missed-call-voice-mail), though.